Rocksdb Compilation issue after upgrading Macos
I upgraded my macos to latest version and from then I am facing the below issue while compiling Rocksdb-5.8
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::lock_guard<std::mutex>'

Code:
size_t size() const {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(lock_);
  return buffer_.size();
}

MacOS version: 14.4.1
Clang version: 15.0.0
I tried downloading llvm@13 via brew and compiling but it didn't work even though it used to compile with previous MacOS version so I want to know what might be the reason causing this I even tried changing -isysroot, setting LDFLAGS & CPPFLAGS (which brew suggested).
PS: I know RocksDB-5.8 is deprecated but its just what we are using at work. I also know the code fix for this(removing const) but I want to know why this error is occuring with os upgrade even after I tried with older version of Clang.
